# Is there a faster way to recompile in C without deleting my executable then making a new one?

Tags: c, compilation

In reality it's really not that big of a deal but if there was a way to maybe just have to input one command and recompile that would be cool.

Comment: How many source files do you have in your project?

Comment: I only have 1 source file

Comment: Use a makefile.

Comment: Are you asking how to *compile* faster or how to trigger the compilation process faster?

Comment: Trigger it faster

Comment: Many ways. Makefile, script, one-liner containing both commands, using IDE with "build" button

Comment: MSVC I use a batch file. I don't have to keep typing the same thing, just a single command, such as `vcmake`.

Comment: With every compiler I've used, if the compiler generates a new executable (strictly speaking it's the linker that does this, but the compiler command often invokes the linker implicitly), it will simply replace any existing executable file with the same name. You don't need to remove it explicitly. On my system: `gcc hello.c -o hello` *creates executable "hello"* (modify hello.c) `gcc hello.c -o hello` *(recompiles, relinks, and replaces executable file "hello")*.

Comment: Yes there is a way. Incremental link and "edit and continue" in Microsoft's Visual C++

Comment: How about NOT deleting the executable and just recompiling? (And relinking, of course, but that's usually automatic.) That will overwrite the executable file with the new contents on all the compilers I've used.